# Ajuda com Editor de Texto e Executável em C

Tags: c, atom

Eu desenvolvi um algoritmo em C para contagem de pedidos, quando compilo dentro do Editor de texto (ATOM), ele executa tudo corretamente.
Porém quando vou no executável gerado na pasta do projeto, ele encerra sem terminar todas as funções.

```
#include <stdio.h>      //CONTROLE DE PEDIDOS
#include <stdlib.h>       //iLLOGICAL
#include <conio.h>          // 21/05/2019

void cabecalho()
{
    printf ("\t|----------------------|\n");
    printf ("\t|     PLAY LANCHES     |\n");
    printf ("\t|                      |\n");
    printf ("\t|     Fechamento       |\n");
    printf ("\t|         de           |\n");
    printf ("\t|       pedidos        |\n");
    printf ("\t|----------------------|\n");
}

int main()
{
    int QtdPedidos, i, j, k;
    int RespTC, RespCerteza, RespCerteza2, RespCerteza3, AcrescentarValor;
    float ValorPedido = 0, TotalPedidos = 0, valor[20];
    float ValorAdicional = 0, TotalGeral = 0, subtracao, ValorSubtraido = 0;
    float TotalGeral2;

    do
    {
        aqui:    cabecalho();

        printf ("\nDigite a quantidade de pedidos: ");
        scanf (" %d", &QtdPedidos);

        printf ("\nTem certeza? [1] SIM [2] N%cO\n", 199);
        scanf (" %d", &RespTC);

        if (RespTC == 2)
        {
            system("cls");
            goto aqui;
            cabecalho();
        }

    } while (RespTC == 2);

        system ("cls");
        cabecalho();
        printf ("\nQuantidade de pedidos = %d\n", QtdPedidos);

        for (i = 1; i <= QtdPedidos; i++)
        {
    inicio: printf ("\nDigite o valor do %d pedido: R$ ", i);
            scanf ("%f", &ValorPedido);

            valor[i] = ValorPedido;
            TotalPedidos = TotalPedidos + ValorPedido;

            printf ("Tem certeza: [1] SIM [2] N%cO\n", 199);
            scanf ("%d", &RespCerteza);

            if (RespCerteza == 2)
            {
                TotalPedidos = TotalPedidos - ValorPedido;
                goto inicio;
            }
        }
            system("cls");
            cabecalho();

            printf ("\nQuantidade de pedidos = %d\n", QtdPedidos);

            printf ("-----------------------------\n");
            for (i = 1; i <= QtdPedidos; i++)
            {
                printf ("Valor pedido %d = R$ %.2f\n", i, valor[i]);
            }
            printf ("-----------------------------\n");
            printf ("\nValor total dos pedidos = R$ %.2f", TotalPedidos);

            printf ("\n\nDeseja acrescentar algum valor: (TROCO...) [1] SIM [2] N%cO\n", 199);
            scanf (" %d", &AcrescentarValor);

            if (AcrescentarValor == 1)
            {
              printf ("\nDigite o valor a ser adicionado: R$ ");
              scanf (" %f", &ValorAdicional);
            }

              TotalGeral = ValorAdicional + TotalPedidos;

              printf ("\nDeseja SUBTRAIR algum valor: [1] SIM [2] N%cO\n", 199);
              scanf (" %d", &RespCerteza3);

              if (RespCerteza3 == 1)
              {
                  printf ("Digite o valor a ser removido: R$ ");
                  scanf (" %f", &ValorSubtraido);
              }


              TotalGeral2 = TotalGeral - ValorSubtraido;

              system("cls");

              cabecalho();
              printf ("\n****************************************************\n");
              printf ("\nQuantidade de pedidos = %d\n", QtdPedidos);
              printf ("_________________________________");
              for (i = 1; i <= QtdPedidos; i++)
              {
                  printf("\n");
                  printf ("Valor pedido %d = R$ %.2f\n", i, valor[i]);
              }
                  printf ("_________________________________\n");
                  printf ("\nValor TOTAL dos pedidos = R$ %.2f\n", TotalPedidos);
              printf ("_________________________________\n");
              printf ("                                                     \n");
              printf ("Valor Adicionado = R$ %.2f\n", ValorAdicional);
              printf ("                                                    \n");
              printf ("\nVALOR TOTAL COM ADI%c%cES = R$ %.2f\n", 128,229, TotalGeral);
              printf ("                                                    \n");
              printf ("\nValor subtraido = R$ %.2f", ValorSubtraido);
              printf ("                                                    \n");
              printf ("\nTOTAL COM ADI%cO E SUBTRA%c%cO = R$ %.2f", 199, 128, 199, TotalGeral2);
              printf ("\n\n**************************************************\n");

              printf ("PRESSIONE ENTER DUAS VEZES PARA SAIR...\n");




  getch();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um dos motivos talvez seja o uso de `conio.h`que não é recomendado. O código tem várias coisas esquisitas então poderia ser muita coisa.

Comment: Recomendo não utilizar goto em seus códigos

Comment: Trechos de código repetidos e totalmente desnecessários.

Comment: Obrigado, galera. :)